# Standard deviation error for EcoTest.sample

Tags: r, warnings

I am using EcoTest.sample to compare rarefaction curves for 19 vegetation plots on two soil types (alluvial and canyon). The code below produces the following

> warning (more than 50 times): "In cor(x > 0) : the standard deviation is zero".

The test still produces all the expected output. Should I be concerned about the warnings? Is it a result of my relatively small sample size?

```
rawdata<-read.table(text="Plot  SiteType    sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4 sp5 sp6 sp7 sp8 sp9 sp10    sp11    sp12    sp13    sp14    sp15    sp16    sp17    sp18    sp19    sp20    sp21    sp22    sp23    sp24    sp25    sp26    sp27    sp28    sp29    sp30    sp31    sp32    sp33    sp34    sp35
2   canyon  1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
3   alluvial    1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
5   alluvial    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
6   alluvial    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
7   alluvial    1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
8   alluvial    1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
10  alluvial    1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
11  canyon  1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
12  canyon  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
14  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
16  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
19  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
20  canyon  1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
22  alluvial    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
23  alluvial    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
", header=T)


data<-rawdata[,-1]
rownames(data)<-rawdata[,1]

test.data<-EcoTest.sample(data[,-1], by=data$SiteType, MARGIN=1, trace=F)
```

Comment: What package is `EcoTest.sample` from?

Comment: If the standard deviation is zero, what happens to the statistical "significance" of your results?

Comment: Like here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233834/what-is-the-normal-distribution-when-standard-deviation-is-zero

Comment: EcoTest.sample is from the rareNMtests package. In spite of the warnings, I still get some significant differences between groups in other subsets of this dataset; p values for this particular group of data are around 0.13.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Perhaps you need to set the nature of the index using `q`. For instance if I use `q=2` the inverse Simpson index, I cannot reproduce your error. As it stands you're using q=0, the species richness. Perhaps there's nothing to do rather than using a different index. I'm not aware of the factors affecting index choice. I've read a thing or two here: http://www.tiem.utk.edu/~gross/bioed/bealsmodules/shannonDI.html and found this paper that I didn't go into much detail: https://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2Fece3.1155
**Using Simpson's index**: No warnings.

```
test.data<-EcoTest.sample(data[,-1], by=data$SiteType, MARGIN=1, trace=F,q=2)
Sample-based method 
P(Obs <= null) =  0.205
```

As stated in this answer on SE, a standard deviation of zero will have an impact on the nature of the distribution. Therefore, any tests you perform that may have depended on a normal distribution will likely be erroneous. The p-values obtained say by a t-test may therefore be "insignificant."

> When standard deviation is zero, your Gaussian (normal) PDF turns into Dirac delta function. You can't simply plug zero standard deviation into the conventional expression. For instance, if the PDF is plugged into some kind of numerical integration, this won't work. (Aksakal on SE)
>   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233834/what-is-the-normal-distribution-when-standard-deviation-is-zero

Comment: Any idea why the test is giving me this warning? I would like to know whether it is a characteristic of the dataset or perhaps a coding issue.

Comment: It seems more like a characteristic of the data set. I got a similar error earlier today while attempting to do some correlation tests. Why is it mostly 1s and 0s?

Comment: EcoTest.sample uses a presence-absence matrix of species for analysis. 1 = species present in that plot; 0 = species absent from that plot. More info here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rareNMtests/versions/1.1/topics/EcoTest.individual

Comment: Hi, please check my edit. I'm no expert on the subject. Perhaps an expert will come along and answer too. Cheers!